# Validation errors in dialog not updating after failed submit in JSF

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

So I click a button which opens a dialog. Inside this dialog I want to fill out information in a form and submit and save it. Some of the inputTexts need to be required in order to submit. So I use the required="true" attribute. It stops the submission, but it does not update the field with a red outline of everything. Now, if I hit cancel and open up the dialog again it will show the fields that failed validation with a red outline!

I thought I could solve this by manually updating the dialog whenever I try to submit the form. This just causes the dialog to close though instead of staying open and refreshing the dialog to show the validation failures.

This is the dialog, when I hit the save button is when I submit the form

```
<h:form>

    <p:dialog header="#{headerValue}" widgetVar="#{uniqueId}_editDialog"
        modal="false" showEffect="fade" styleClass="dialogGrid"
        dynamic="true" draggable="true" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel style="text-align:center;" layout="block">
         <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
            <ui:insert name="editContent">
      Edit Content Here. Use 'selectedModel.whatever'
    </ui:insert>
            <p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="buttonGrid">
                <ui:insert name="saveButton">
                    <p:commandButton iconPos="left" value="#{msg.save}"
                        rendered="#{'VIEW' != selectedModel.viewState}"
                        process="@widgetVar(#{uniqueId}_editDialog)"
                        action="#{adapterInjector.add(modelList, selectedModel)}"
                        update="@widgetVar(#{uniqueId}_itemsDataList) @widgetVar(#{uniqueId}_addButton) @widgetVar(#{uniqueId}_editDialog)"
                        oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed) PF('#{uniqueId}_editDialog').hide()"
                        partialSubmit="true" validateClient="true">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </ui:insert>

                <p:commandButton iconPos="right" value="#{msg.cancel}"
                    process="@this" oncomplete="PF('#{uniqueId}_editDialog').hide()"
                    resetValues="true" partialSubmit="true">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

This is an inserted component which has the required attribute

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="licenseCert"
                    value="#{selectedModel.selectedLicenseCert}" filter="true"
                    required="true">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.selectOne}" itemValue=""
                        noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{licCert.allLicenseCertMap.entrySet()}"
                        var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it. For best practice you should: 1) move the `<h:form>` inside the dialog and 2) `process` the moved `<h:form>` in the save button.

Comment: I've added it as a regular answer for future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this fixed the problem.

For best practice you should:

1. move the `<h:form>` inside the dialog
2. process the moved `<h:form>` in the save button.

Comment: What do you mean by the second instruction?

Thank you very much

Comment: @unpix: I usually advise against submitting/processing data outside of a form, so by #2, I meant that you should change `<h:form>...<p:commandButton value="Save" process="@widgetVar(#{uniqueId}_editDialog)"` to `<h:form id="#{uniqueId}_Form">... <p:commandButton value="Save" process="#{uniqueId}_Form"` or similar.